# Javafx Event handler on GridPane Cells

Tags: java, javafx

I have the gridpane set up just fine. But how to put event handler in each cell? Like mouse double click and right click. 
Could someone give me an example, please? Thank you!

Comment: Add the event handler to the node which you are adding to the GridPane.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you want exactly,but i hope this examples can help you

**First example**  (I add the same event for all nodes)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackover;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Ala_Eddine
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        addGridEvent();

    }

    private void addGridEvent() {
        gridPane.getChildren().forEach(item -> {
            item.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        System.out.println("doubleClick");
                    }
                    if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        System.out.println("PrimaryKey event");
                    }

                }
            });

        });
    }

**}
```

Second example**

```
private void addGridEvent() {

        Button button = new Button("hi");
        //You can use OnAction 
        button.addEventHandler(EventType.ROOT, (event) -> {
            if (event.getEventType() == ActionEvent.ACTION) {
                System.out.println("ActionEvent");
            }
        });
        gridPane.getChildren().add(button);
```